# Centering UILabel not working?

Tags: ios, swift

I have to programmatically center my UILabel so that the center of its text is in the center of the screen at all times. However, I keep getting it so the left hand side seems horizontally centered instead:

[image: pic]

I'm using the following code to do this:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.center = self.view.center
label.textAlignment = .center
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

So I want the label to have equal margins horizontally, and the text within to be centered as well. Note that I have to do this programatically unfortunetely. Can anybody help me see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using autolayout

Comment: No, the only other thing I'm doing is `theLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true` to fix its width

Comment: then you should add more constraint!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Try call this code in your `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: write [self.view layoutIfNeeded] in view did load or write above label code to viewWillAppear method

Comment: tried `label.frame = self.view.frame` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set `centerXAnchor` and `centerYAnchor` programmatically:

```
view.addSubview(label)
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant:0).isActive = true
label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant:0).isActive = true
label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
```

This should help you

Comment: In addition to this, he doesn't have to manually set the height of the label. The intrinsic content size of the text will deal with resizing as needed.

Comment: I tried doing this in my viewDidLoad but am getting a runtime error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x608001073c00 "UILabel:0x7fafab539a30.centerX"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x608001265400 "UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView:0x7fafab40ecf0.centerX"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'`

Comment: @MarksCode You can set up constraints programmatically when you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` into false and add a view to his subview. Then you're able to set constraints. Check my edited answer

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding it as a subview before setting the constraints, but for some reason it's showing up at the top of the view: http://imgur.com/a/AWcqm. Going to try out your edited answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You should pin `horizontally in container, Vertically in container, fixed width and fixed heigh`, this four constraints to your `label`. This four constraints will  always keep your label in center of your screen!

Comment: Is this something I can do programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

try this without adding any constraint

```
  label.center = CGPointMake((self.view.frame.size.width - label.frame.size.width) / 2 , (self.view.frame.size.height - label.frame.size.height) / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the view is using constraints.
If you want to use the `center` property you should probably set the value after the view has layout itself, so in your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `layoutSubviews` methods (first one is for view controllers, the second one for views).

The other way is to set the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `label.sizeToFit()` its should help

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its working for me

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.frame.size.height/2, 200, 21))
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
label.text = "I'am a test label"
label.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2)
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove leading and trailing constraints. I centered it horizontally in the view and set its vertical spacing to be relative to another view.